# angularjs route does not work Argument 'CatCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I below app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/categories', {
            templateUrl: 'views/cat.view.html',
            controller: 'CatCtrl'
        })
    }]);
```

Here is CatCtrl.js file

```
angular.module('base').controller('CatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/categories').success(function (data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
    });
}]);
```

Here is cat.view.html

```
<div ng-controller="CatCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="categories">
              Cats View
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already add `ng-app="base"` to my index.html file.

I am geting following error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CatCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am using `angularjs 1.4.7`.

I already looked at other answers on stackoverflow to solve this problem but none of them worked for me. **How can I resolve this error?**

**UPDATE**

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6eIRWCBs5VH8sqOKqobP?p=info)

Comment: in your CatCtrl the name of your controller was 'CategoriesCtrl' so in your ng-controller it muse be ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl"

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency like

```
var app = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute', 'kB']);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I added dependency but still does not work. I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

From your plunker you can see that your templateUrl is wrong, it must be the path to your .html file.

edit : name edited in question ->

> Your controller's name is 'CategoriesCtrl'. 'CatCtrl' is just the name
>   of the file that you are going to include in the index.html
>
> ```
> <div ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl">
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="categories">
>               Cats View
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
>
> var app = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute']);
>
> app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
>     $routeProvider.
>         when('/categories', {
>             templateUrl: 'views/cat.view.html',
>             controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
>         })
> }]);
> ```

Comment: I know, it still does not work. I am getting same error.

Comment: Verify your kb module declaration and injection then.

Comment: where is your kb module declared ?

Comment: Actually that is base not kB. Now I fixed it but still same error.

Comment: I created a plunk. Please see the link in updated question.

Comment: @2619 your template Url is wrong, it must be the path to the .html file

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to make two small changes -

1. First, I didn't see any **CatCtrl** in your code.Change this line

   angular.module('kB').controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',

   to

   angular.module('kB').controller('CatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
2. Second, since the Controller is defined in a different module (KB) than base, you need to inject the module into base, iof you wish to use the controller

   var app = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute', 'kB']);

Last point - 
Since you are alrady mentioning the **CatCtrl** in routing, no need to use it again in your view.

Comment: I already fixed 1 and 2 points. I also removed CatCtrl from view and I still getting same error.

Comment: better create a plunk / jsfiddle .

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo

http://dojo.telerik.com/EFUJo

```
var app = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('base').controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/categories').success(function (data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
});
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/categories', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cat.view.html',
        controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
    })
}]);
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: Where are you creating cat.view.html? It is in the body which means it will render anyway.

Comment: The basic logic of your code is the same as mine code. Could you tell me the difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: template url is different